# How to SUM two rows with the same substring in EXCEL

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, ms-office, excel-2010

I have a small set of browser usage data in a CVS file:

```
Browser | Hits
IE 9    | 5
IE 6    | 45
IE 7    | 33
Chrome  | 122 
Firefox | 8
```

I want to aggregate based on a common substring in the Browser column (for example all browser values containing 'IE'):

```
Browser | Hits
IE      | 83
Chrome  | 122 
Firefox | 8
```

Would this be easier to do in SQL Server with a query?  If so, that answer would be fine too.

Comment: Does the data start out in a database?

Comment: is it an option to create another column in Excel as =LEFT(<Browser>,2) and include this as a row label field in a Pivot table?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need array formulas in excel - you can use SUMIF with wildcards

`=SUMIF(A:A,E3&"*",B:B)`

where E3 contains the search criteria like **"chrome"**

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, try searching for the substring with SEARCH,

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("IE", A2), 0), B2,0)
```

Which will give the value of A2 (the Hits) if A1 (Browser) contains the string "IE". Then from there you can build a pivot. See [IF a cell contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867448/if-a-cell-contains-a-string) .

In T-SQL, you could have a view like this:

```
SELECT 
  Browser = 'IE'
  Hits = SUM(CASE WHEN [Browser] LIKE '%IE%' THEN [Hits] ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
  MyTable 
UNION 
SELECT 
  Browser = 'Mozilla'
  Hits = SUM(CASE WHEN [Browser] LIKE '%Mozilla%' THEN [Hits] ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
  MyTable
```

etc.

But see Barry Houdini below.

Answer (score 0):

Select Browser, Count(Hits)
From (your table)
Group by Browser.

See if that Works in

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in Excel is to put the values you want in a column and to use array function.  For instance, put the values starting E3:

```
IE
Chrome
Firefox
```

Then use conditional aggregation.  Assuming the data is in A1 to B1000 (with the first row being a header), then the formula in F3 would be:

```
{sum(if(isnumber(search(E3, $A$2:$A:$1000)) > 0, $B$2:$B$1000))}
```

Note that this is an array function which you create using ctrl-shift-enter (look up the topic on the web).  You can then copy the function down the column.

If the data is originally in a SQL database, then it is easier to get the answer there without going through a CSV file.  However, it would be helpful if you gave an idea of the original data format.